# Clean up the surface on WaterMark of an Image

Tags: c#, asp.net, drawing, watermark

There is an image for the surface, and a text is written on the image for 184 rows of date..
Thus, it is expected to see 184 different text written image files are generated with all the same background images. (The code is declared below...)

The problem is that the first text is written for all 184 different data.. I think I have to remove something in the loop. But what is that ??

```
 for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) {
            date = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i]["PAYMENT_DATE"]);
            branchCode = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["BRANCH_CODE"]);
            refNum = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["REF_NUM"]);
            accountNumber = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["ACCOUNT_NUMBER"]);
            email = dt.Rows[i]["EMAIL"].ToString();
            tableCode = dt.Rows[i]["CUSTOMER_TABLE_CODE"].ToString();

            TranLogKey logKey = new TranLogKey(date, branchCode, refNum);
            TranLogEntry entry = Log.SelectLogEntry(logKey, false);
            if (Intertech.Core.Framework.Context.CurrentContext.LogEntry == null)
                Intertech.Core.Framework.Context.CurrentContext.LogEntry = entry;

            try {
                receiptText = TransactionManager.GenerateReceipt(true, logKey, null, null, accountNumber, false);
            }
            catch (Exception exp) {
                continue;
            }

            if (receiptText != null) {
                if (receiptText.IndexOf("SURETTİR\r\n") != -1)
                    receiptText = receiptText.Substring(receiptText.IndexOf("SURETTİR\r\n") + 10).Trim();

                if (receiptText.IndexOf("İşlemi Yapan") != -1)
                    receiptText = receiptText.Substring(0, receiptText.IndexOf("İşlemi Yapan"));
                if (receiptText.IndexOf("MÜŞTERİ İMZASI") != -1)
                    receiptText = receiptText.Substring(0, receiptText.IndexOf("MÜŞTERİ İMZASI"));

                Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(imageDir);
                Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
                SizeF size;
                Font font = new Font("Courier New", 8, FontStyle.Regular);
                byte ALPHA = 200;
                size = g.MeasureString(receiptText, font);
                Bitmap waterbmp = new Bitmap((int)size.Width, (int)size.Height);
                Graphics waterg = Graphics.FromImage(waterbmp);
                waterg.DrawString(receiptText, font, new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black), 2, 2);
                DrawWatermark(ref waterbmp, ref bmp, LeftIndex, TopIndex, ALPHA);
                bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                try {


                        GoServices.Core.SendMailOutside("The Portugal Life", "info@portugal.tr.friendship.pt",
                                    "blgnklc@skype-account.com", " e-Wish " + email, "", new string[] { "dekont.jpg" }, new object[] { ms.ToArray() });

                        LogNotificationState("K", refNum, accountNumber, 2, true, null, tableCode);

                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    LogNotificationState("K", 0, -1, 2, false, ex, tableCode);
                }

            }



private static void DrawWatermark(ref Bitmap watermark_bm, ref Bitmap result_bm, int x, int y, byte ALPHA) {
    System.Drawing.Color clr;

    int py, px;
    for (py = 0; py <= watermark_bm.Height - 1; py++) {
        for (px = 0; px <= watermark_bm.Width - 1; px++) {
            clr = watermark_bm.GetPixel(px, py);
            if (clr.A != 0 || clr.R != 0 || clr.G != 0 || clr.B != 0)
                watermark_bm.SetPixel(px, py, System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(ALPHA, clr.R, clr.G, clr.B));
        }
    }
    Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(result_bm);
    gr.DrawImage(watermark_bm, x, y);
}
```

Comment: You will need to show the code of `DrawWatermark` too.

Comment: @I just released that every time I receive an e-mail with the created jpg file, the size is getting bigger and bigger with the same first text on it....

Comment: @Have a look to the code, I added the method of DrawWatermark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at how you are creating the bitmap.

Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(imageDir);

does this line need to be in there everytime, i.e is imagedir the same all the time?

Do you dispose of the generated bitmap after creating it?

what happens in this function:

DrawWatermark(ref waterbmp, ref bmp, LeftIndex, TopIndex, ALPHA);

You seem to then save the bmp file but not dispose of it?

I have seen some strange behaviour from GDI+ so I would start here.

Comment: @Have a look to the code, I added the method of DrawWatermark

Comment: catch (Exception ex) {
                    LogNotificationState("K", 0, -1, 2, false, ex, tableCode);
                }
                bmp.Dispose();
                bmp = null;
     it does not work!

Comment: @I found the answer, I put the  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
in the loop so now it works quite well!

thanks